# Javascript, update div html with dynamic content over time without set interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, setinterval

I know how to do it with `setInterval`, wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it.  I would want the content to be loaded right when the content is updated.  If I did that with `setInterval`, I would have to call the ajax method every second...

I'm using Symfony2, with jQuery (can use core JavaScript if I must).

Comment: Investigate websockets. They allow you to keep a connection open with the server over which the server can communicate to the client to send a signal when new data becomes available.

Comment: Thanks!  Should I try node.js or what is your preference.

Comment: I personally have a websocket setup using the CometD library in a JVM app running under Tomcat and proxied with Apache. There are many many different ways of getting websockets working :)

Comment: You can also use Ajax long polling if you're willing to use only jQuery/Javascript.